# Embed a spreadsheet/table in a PyGTK application?

Tags: python, pygtk, spreadsheet

In my application, we want to present the user with a typical spreadsheet/table (OO.O/Excel-style), and then pull out the values and do something with them internally.

Is there a preexisting widget for PyGTK that does this? The [PyGTK FAQ](http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=all#19.14) mentions [GtkGrid](http://www.sicem.biz/personal/lgs/projects/gtkgrid/view_project), but the link is dead and I can't find a tarball anywhere.

Answer (score 12):

`GtkGrid` is deprecated in favor of the more powerful and more customizable [`GtkTreeView`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/pygtk/stable/class-gtktreeview.html).

It can display trees and lists. To make it work like a table, you must define a [`ListStore`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/pygtk/stable/class-gtkliststore.html) where it will take the data from, and [`TreeViewColumn`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/pygtk/stable/class-gtktreeviewcolumn.html)s for each column you want to show, with [`CellRenderer`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/pygtk/stable/class-pygtkgenericcellrenderer.html)s to define how to show the column. This separation of data and render allows you to render other controls on the cell, like text boxes or images.

`GtkTreeView` is very flexible, but it seems complex at first because of the many options. To help with that, there's the [relevant section](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/ch-TreeViewWidget.html) in the [PyGTK tutorial](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/) (although you should read it entirely, not just this section).

For completeness, here's an example code and a screenshot of it running in my system:

[image: Screenshot-TreeViewColumn Example.png]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk

class TreeViewColumnExample(object):

    # close the window and quit
    def delete_event(self, widget, event, data=None):
        gtk.main_quit()
        return False

    def __init__(self):
        # Create a new window
        self.window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
        self.window.set_title("TreeViewColumn Example")
        self.window.connect("delete_event", self.delete_event)

        # create a liststore with one string column to use as the model
        self.liststore = gtk.ListStore(str, str, str, 'gboolean')

        # create the TreeView using liststore
        self.treeview = gtk.TreeView(self.liststore)

        # create the TreeViewColumns to display the data
        self.tvcolumn = gtk.TreeViewColumn('Pixbuf and Text')
        self.tvcolumn1 = gtk.TreeViewColumn('Text Only')

        # add a row with text and a stock item - color strings for
        # the background
        self.liststore.append(['Open', gtk.STOCK_OPEN, 'Open a File', True])
        self.liststore.append(['New', gtk.STOCK_NEW, 'New File', True])
        self.liststore.append(['Print', gtk.STOCK_PRINT, 'Print File', False])

        # add columns to treeview
        self.treeview.append_column(self.tvcolumn)
        self.treeview.append_column(self.tvcolumn1)

        # create a CellRenderers to render the data
        self.cellpb = gtk.CellRendererPixbuf()
        self.cell = gtk.CellRendererText()
        self.cell1 = gtk.CellRendererText()

        # set background color property
        self.cellpb.set_property('cell-background', 'yellow')
        self.cell.set_property('cell-background', 'cyan')
        self.cell1.set_property('cell-background', 'pink')


        # add the cells to the columns - 2 in the first
        self.tvcolumn.pack_start(self.cellpb, False)
        self.tvcolumn.pack_start(self.cell, True)
        self.tvcolumn1.pack_start(self.cell1, True)

        self.tvcolumn.set_attributes(self.cellpb, stock_id=1)
        self.tvcolumn.set_attributes(self.cell, text=0)
        self.tvcolumn1.set_attributes(self.cell1, text=2,
                                      cell_background_set=3)

        # make treeview searchable
        self.treeview.set_search_column(0)

        # Allow sorting on the column
        self.tvcolumn.set_sort_column_id(0)

        # Allow drag and drop reordering of rows
        self.treeview.set_reorderable(True)

        self.window.add(self.treeview)

        self.window.show_all()

def main():
    gtk.main()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tvcexample = TreeViewColumnExample()
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @nosklo - unfortunately, your original image was dead; so I edited your post and added a screenshot from my system. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

It's perhaps a little more manual than, for instance, a GridView in .Net, but the Tree View widget will do what you need and much more. See [PyGtk TreeView](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/ch-TreeViewWidget.html)

Answer (score 0):

You might consider embedding a web page viewer - you can do a lot with that: http://blog.mypapit.net/2009/09/pymoembed-web-browser-in-python-gtk-application.html