# Excessive hang time when destroying a PyGTK window

Tags: python, gtk

My PyGTK application creates a secondary popup window for displaying a preview of results. This window is fairly elaborate, with Table widgets nested three deep and populated by HBoxes containing one Label each at the lowest level. The number of Labels total can be in the thousands. I am noticing that when I close this window, GTK becomes extremely busy processing something (functions added with gobject.idle_add don't resolve for >10 seconds) and the main window of my application becomes unresponsive in this time. Even with this many widgets, it seems strange to me that the window should take so long to close, longer even than it takes to set up and display. Is there any way to mitigate this? (I tried creating and showing the window in another thread, but apparently with GTK this is a no-no)

Comment: Use a profiler to find out what functions are taking so long.

Comment: Maybe you could first only hide the window and then do the destruction via idle_add. But anyway, it must not be that lengthy. Something is going severely wrong here. Measure it!

Comment: Of the total 61.654 seconds of execution time (including a short amount of time it was waiting for my input), 47.945 seconds were spent in gtk._gtk.main, 8.347 in gtk.Widget.show_all, and 2.587 in gtk.Container.add. It took about 11 seconds (the time spent in show_all and add) to set up and show the window, and 44 seconds (the gtk._gtk.main time, minus the time spent waiting for input) to destroy it. Also, I am apparently really bad at estimating time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was being caused by my attempt to change the background color of the tables--I was setting the background color of every HBox (and Label), which was responsible for nearly all of the excessive teardown time. All I had to do was set the background color of the Viewports the Tables are contained in.

Comment: As I stated above, the real problem is that you're using the wrong widgets.

Comment: Switched to using a TreeView. The performance was good before, but it seems better now.

Answer (score 1):

How long takes that window to show up? Are all the widgets created at once when it is displayed?

Your problem might be caused by the destruction of your thousands of widgets, all at the same time. Or by a lengthy action perform on on of those widgets destruction. But without some code to look at, there could be thousands of reasons, so a ptomato says, use a profiler...

Comment: Virtually all of the time spent setting up and tearing down the window is spent in gtk methods, as I expected. Not sure if there is then any way to save time or keep it from blocking so long, besides using fewer widgets, which isn't really an option. There are a total of about 4000 widgets in the display, which becomes 4000 Labels and 4000 HBoxes to pack them in.

Comment: If you're using 4000 labels and 4000 HBoxes, chances are your problem is not performance, but UI design. Would it be possible to have a screenshot (even partial) of the UI? To understand why you're doing that? BTW, if you often need to reopen that window, just don't close it, hide it using gtk_widget_hide_on_delete. Creation will still be long, but reusing the window and filling it with the new data will be faster than destroying+creating again.

Comment: It's a preview of a .tsv file that has been written, that would be opened and edited in Excel. The number of cells is entirely dependent on what the user specifies--I just thought it seemed to be taking too long relative to the number of cells.

Comment: Your problem is that you're abusing the toolkit by using the wrong widgets. A spreadsheet isn't a aggregate of thousands of widgets, it's usually a single widget optimized for this usage. Please give a look at this question: [Embed a spreadsheet/table in a PyGTK application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1447187/embed-a-spreadsheet-table-in-a-pygtk-application).